Using live site instead of preview
I have completed all steps mentioned here...
https://catalog.workshops.aws/building-with-amazon-bedrock/en-US/intermediate/bedrock-csv
But I have a problem with this:

Ignore the Network URL and External URL links displayed by the
Streamlit command. Instead, we will use AWS Cloud9's preview feature.

I do NOT want to ignore external URL. I need to use it in my broser instead of preview.
Preview is working as expected. But I need the "website" to function as expected.

Make sure your EC2 instance for Cloud9 is accessible from the Internet:

Has a public IP address
Can connect to an Internet gateway

Then modify the security group associated for that instance:

Allow incoming TCP 8080 from your IP addresses

